# Job scheduling is not working in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, jobs, job-scheduling

Created job like below :

```
BEGIN
         Dbms_Scheduler.create_job(
            job_name   => 'PROECSS_STATE'
           ,job_type   => 'STORED_PROCEDURE' 
           ,job_action   => 'ARCHIVE_AND_DELETE' -- Procedure Name
           ,start_date   => SYSDATE
           ,repeat_interval => 'freq=DAILY; byhour=13' --Added byhour
           ,enabled   => TRUE
           ,comments   => 'job schedule for archiving process_state');
END;
```

When i created the job, the time was "21-mrt-2014 12:55:55"

But nothing has happened after checking( Checked at 13:05:45).

Procedure did not run as expected.

Can any one please tell me why job has not been executed?

Comment: Check if Your procedure is valid.

Comment: Procedure is working fine.

Comment: Does this procedure take parameters on input?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `start_date => SYSDATE` with `start_date => SYSTIMESTAMP`.

This is only a problem on some problems.  For example, the code below runs 2 jobs on Oracle 12c on Windows, but only runs the first job on 11gR2 on Solaris.

```
begin
    dbms_scheduler.create_job('TEST_JOB1', 'PLSQL_BLOCK', 'begin null; end;'
        ,start_date => systimestamp, enabled => true);
    dbms_scheduler.create_job('TEST_JOB2', 'PLSQL_BLOCK', 'begin null; end;'
        ,start_date => sysdate     , enabled => true);
end;
/

--Only one job ran (on some platforms).
select * from dba_scheduler_job_run_details where job_name like 'TEST%';
```

I do not know why this happens.  I would appreciate it if anyone could explain it.

Comment: Tried with SYSTIMESTAMP instead of SYSDATE. Not working. @jonearles

Comment: D'oh.  Can you check the output of `select * from dba_scheduler_jobs where job_name = 'PROECSS_STATE';` and 
`select * from dba_scheduler_job_run_details where job_name = 'PROECSS_STATE';`.  Did the job run, but fail?

Comment: Both tables does not exist. Hence throwing the exception "Table/View does not exist". I wonder where these jobs are storing then? I tried even 'select * from user_jobs' but no luck. Any idea where the jobs are being stored ??  ..@jonearles

Comment: Try `all_` instead of `dba_`.